# Update column for all rows in first group

Tags: python, pandas

I need to update the value of a column for all rows in the first group of a dataframe. For example I have the following df:

```
date          amount
2019-01-01    10
2019-01-01    14
2019-02-01    16
2019-02-01    34
2019-03-01    36
2019-04-01    25
2019-04-01    45
2019-05-01    23
```

I need to group by date and set all `amount` values in the first group to 0. The result is:

```
date          amount
2019-01-01    0
2019-01-01    0
2019-02-01    16
2019-02-01    34
2019-03-01    36
2019-04-01    25
2019-04-01    45
2019-05-01    23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create mask by compare first value of `date` by all values and set `0` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['date'].eq(df['date'].iat[0]), 'amount'] = 0
print (df)
         date  amount
0  2019-01-01       0
1  2019-01-01       0
2  2019-02-01      16
3  2019-02-01      34
4  2019-03-01      36
5  2019-04-01      25
6  2019-04-01      45
7  2019-05-01      23
```

Another idea with [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df.loc[df['date'].rank(method='dense').eq(1), 'amount'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) and [ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#enumerate-groups) :

```
df.loc[df.groupby("date").ngroup().eq(0), "amount"] = 0
```